# Smallest Largest Sum of Paired Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, grouping

I have an array of integers which has even length. As an example, letš take an array `{0, 6, 4, 22, 19, 11}`. Pairing all the numbers into pairs, I have to find the largest pair sum. Now, out of all possible combinations I must find the case when the largest of pair sums is the smallest.
In this case it would be 23 (when the pairs are 0-22, 4-19, 6-11).

Now the only case I can think of is checking for every possible set of pair sums, finding the largest pair and checking if it is smaller than the last time. This, however, is incredibly inefficient as it requires looping through the array as much as it's length squared times. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to do it.

I am considering that sorting the array and finding the largest sum choosing pairs from the first and last elements, then moving inwards, could work, but I am not sure if this is true in all the cases.

Comment: And your question is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is true for all the cases! Can be proved mathematically!

Assume 2N numbers a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, ..., a_2N are non-decreasing numbers (after sorted). Then the pairs are

a_1 and a_2N

a_2 and a_2N-1

...

a_N and a_N+1

the maximum of these sums will be the smallest.

Assume the a_i and a_2N+1-i pair gets the maximum value MAX.

then we will change the pairs to see if we can get a smaller maximum. So a_2N+1-i can only be paired to a_1, a_2, ..., a_i-1 to get a smaller maximum, similarly, a_2N+2-i also can only be paired to a_1, a_2, ..., a_i-1, ..., so for a_2N.

In total we have i numbers (a_2N+1-i, ..., a_2N) have to paired to i-1 numbers (a_1, a_2, ..., a_i-1), which is impossible.

So we can get the conclusion proved.

I'm not sure if I have statement this clearly.

Best Luck!

Comment: It seems to be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Can you show me the proof? I need to see it in order to assume it completely true.

Comment: Modified the brief prove in the answer.